# How to debug: Client gets 502 but nginx logs 200

Tags: nginx, twilio, webhooks

I'm having trouble debugging a webhook. I have a Node app behind an nginx reverse proxy that handles webhook requests from Twilio.

When Twilio POSTs to my webhook URL, I see the request is passed through to my Node app, which handles it correctly and returns an empty 200 status. In my nginx access logs, I see an HTTP 200 response to Twilio (and nothing in the error log which is set at notice level). However, Twilio reports that it received an empty 502 Bad Gateway response in my debugging console.

I'm not sure how to proceed with debugging this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried sending back a valid XML as I think that's what Twilio expects?

Comment: See if you can generate some logs using technique mentioned in this http://tarunlalwani.com/post/how-to-debug-nginx-reverse-proxy-issues-php-fpm-gunicorn-uwsgi/

Comment: It looks like it @AlexBaban nailed it. After reading your comment I found [this little gem](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/your_response#status-callbacks) in the TwiML docs. I also re-read the notes in the debugging console and it explains what Twilio means by 502 error (basically: "when we don't like what we get back, we call it a 502 error"). I find this _extremely_ confusing especially since farther down on the page it says "Server_returned_status_502_when_requesting_callback_URL" which is not the case. Oh well. If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio recommends that you respond to status callbacks with either a
`204 No Content` or a
`200 OK` with **`Content-Type: text/xml`** and an empty `<Response/>` in the body.

Failure to respond properly will result in warnings in Debugger.

***Valid XML response:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response/>
```

As `@Dominic P` noted in comments read more on the docs at:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/your_response#status-callbacks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried sending a 204 no content from node? Can you post your node code that receives the POST (that your webook is pointed to) ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll give it a try. The node code is quite long, but the very first line of the handler function sends the response to Twilio. That line currently looks like this: `res.status(200).send();`

Comment: doing a res.send immediately I believe ends the post, which means it would contain nothing but a response code, so that would only work if you sent it empty 204 OR 200 OK with Content-Type: text/xml, but not an empty 200